# Install JMeter plugin

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-plugins

I have another little question about JMeter.

In my PC I have a JMeter installation where I downloaded some plugins with the Plugins Manager.

I'm running some tests on 3 different Linux VMs (1 master and 2 slaves). To install the same plugins in these VMs, can I simply copy the .jar plugin file to the lib/ext/ folder or do I have to go through the Plugin Manager in these VMs too? Both my PC and the VMs are running JMeter 4.0

One 2nd question, do I need the plugin on the slaves VMs or just the one in the master VM is enough?

Thanks in advance for your help,

Best regards,
Marc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It is enough to copy the .jar file(s) to the slave machines, installing the [plugins manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/) itself is not necessary. Mind that some plugins add dependencies into JMeter's "lib" folder therefore make sure that "lib" folder is also in sync with what you have on the master node.
2. You need to have any plugins on slaves. Same applies to CSV data files, properties files, whatever. Master node only sends a .jmx scripts and global properties you specify via [`-G` command-line argument](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#options), you need to take care of plugins and data on your own.

More information: [How to Perform Distributed Testing in JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-perform-distributed-testing-in-jmeter)

Comment: Thank you again :)

Answer (score 0):

You **must** have same version of JMeter, and also if you are using other plugins for [Distributed testing](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/remote-test.html):

> Make sure that all the nodes (client and servers) : are running exactly the same version of JMeter.

You can follow [local repository of jmeter plugins](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-create--local-repository-of-jmeter-plugins) tutorial by Guy Salton

Solution is to have only one specific place for your JMeter plugins:

> Add the following line to the jmeter.properties file:
>
> ```
> jpgc.repo.address=http://10.129.66.91:8080/my_plugins.json
> ```

where `10.129.66.91` is the IP of the repository machine

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I'm over charged right now, I'll do a manual copy as Dmitri suggested, but I'll take the time to look into your tutorial latter...